# How to Install Libraries in .yaml file into data bricks cluster. I am aware of .txt to install but Yaml can only install using %conda command

Tags: installation, yaml, cluster-computing, databricks, libraries

I like to install Libraries into databricks using .yaml file.

I am aware of .txt file where I can install the all the libraries in signal attempt

I want the same method where I can install all the libraries in YAML file on databricks cluster